# How to speed up integers finding function?

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction

Playing with integers I looked for a way of finding, let's say, $4$-digits positive integers such that $a,b,a+b$ had the same digits, like $$1089 + 8019 = 9108$$
I am a newbie and I used this function

```
sd[a_, b_] := 
 If[Mod[a, 9] != 0 || Mod[b, 9] != 0 , False, 
  Sort[IntegerDigits[a + b]] == Sort[IntegerDigits[a]] && 
   Sort[IntegerDigits[a]] == Sort[IntegerDigits[b]]]
```

Then I used the function in this way

```
Select[Flatten[
  Table[{h, k, sd[h, k]}, {h, 1000, 10000}, {k, h, 10000}], 1], #[[3]] &]
```

But it took ages to give the output.

Is there a way to speed up this procedure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't the iterators in the table be `Table[...,  {h, 1000, 10000 - 1}, {k, h, 10000 - h - 1}]`?

Comment: The fastest way to find integers is to not lose them in the first place. Just saying.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ClearAll[pairS]

pairS[n_] := SortBy[First] @
  Apply[Join] @
   KeyValueMap[Function[{k, v},
      Select[k == Sort@IntegerDigits@Total@# &]@Subsets[v, {2}]]] @
    GroupBy[Sort@*IntegerDigits] @
     (999 + 9 Range[10^(n - 1)])
```

***Examples:***

```
 pairS[4] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.0445052
> ```

```
pairS[5] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.19877
> ```

```
Multicolumn[pairS[4], 5]
```

[image]

```
Length @ pairS[5]
```

> ```
> 673
> ```

```
pairS[5] // Short[#, 7] &
```

[image]

**An aside:** A slower graph-based method: get the edge list of a graph where the numbers $a$ and $b$ are connected if $a$, $b$ and $a+b$ have the same integer digits.

```
relation = Sort[IntegerDigits @ #] == Sort[IntegerDigits @ #2] == 
    Sort[IntegerDigits[# + #2]] &;

relationgraph = RelationGraph[relation, 999 + 9 Range[10^(4 - 1)]];

edges = EdgeList @ relationgraph;
 
List @@@ edges == pairS[4]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Subgraph[relationgraph, VertexList[edges], 
 GraphLayout -> "MultipartiteEmbedding", 
 GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: I'll spend next week studying your answer. Thank you

Comment: On my laptop the $5$-digits version took almost 6 minutes. I wrote a simple program in Pascal and it took about 28 seconds. Can you explain in simple words  the reason why this happens?

Comment: @Raffaele I think the main problem is generating all the possible candidates beforehand, which gets very memory-intensive. Once the RAM on your computer fills up and it becomes necessary to swap memory to disk, things slow down dramatically.

Comment: @Rafaelle, updated with a much faster version.

Comment: I'll spend next TWO weeks studying your code. TY

Comment: Amazing! all 17,338 triplets of 6 digits numbers in 70 seconds!

Comment: Maybe you should correct 999 + 9 Range[10^(n - 1)] in 10^(n - 1) +  9 Range[10^(n - 1)]

Comment: Amazing performance!

Answer (score 5):

https://oeis.org/A331468

> The numbers of 3-digit to 8-digit triples are: 1, 25, 648, 17338, 495014, and 17565942.

**Approach 1, more concise**

```
Clear[search];
search[n_] := 
   Join @@ Table[With[{s = Subsets[a, {2}]}, 
     Pick[s, Boole@MemberQ[a, Total@#] & /@ s, 1]], 
      {a, GatherBy[Select[Range[10^(n - 1), 10^n - 1], Divisible[#, 9] &], 
        Sort@*IntegerDigits]}];

search[4] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
search[5] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
search[6] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0210189, 25}
> {0.212638, 648}
> {9.23615, 17338}

**Approach 2, more efficient**

```
Clear[cf]
cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {A, _Integer, 2}},
   Module[{nums, ni, nj, B = Internal`Bag[Most@{0}]},
    Do[
     nums = Permutations[a]. 10^Range[n - 1, 0, -1];
     Do[
      ni = nums[[i]];
      nj = nums[[j]];
      If[ni + nj > 10^n || ni < 10^(n - 1), Break[]];
      Do[If[ni + nj == k, Internal`StuffBag[B, {ni, nj, k}, 1]; Break[]]
       , {k, nums}]
      , {i, Length@nums}, {j, i + 1, Length@nums}]
     , {a, A}];
    Internal`BagPart[B, All]
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

n = 4;
AbsoluteTiming[
 digits = Select[# - Range[n] & /@ Subsets[Range[9 + n], {n}], Divisible[Total@#, 9] &];
 Length[ans = Partition[cf[n, digits], 3]]
 ]
```

For `n=4,5,6`

> {0.0014472, 25}
> {0.0094707, 648}
> {0.802517, 17338}

Compare with kglr's answer

```
ClearAll[pairS]
pairS[n_] := 
  Apply[Join]@ KeyValueMap[Function[{k, v}, 
   Select[k == Sort@IntegerDigits@Total@# &]@Subsets[v, {2}]]]@
    GroupBy[Sort@*IntegerDigits]@(10^(n - 1) - 1 + 9 Range[10^(n - 1)])

pairS[4] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
pairS[5] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
pairS[6] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0362128, 25}
> {0.945485, 648}
> {40.879, 17338}

**Approach 3, Using LibraryLink, 10 times faster again**

```
src="#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <WolframLibrary.h>

void solve(int *a, int level, int n, int start, std::vector<int> &res) {
    if (level == n) {
        if (std::accumulate(a, a + n, 0) % 9 == 0) {
            std::vector<int> vec;
            do {
                if (a[0] != 0)
                    vec.push_back(std::accumulate(a, a + n, 0, 
                      [&](int x, int y) { return 10 * x + y; }));
            } while (std::next_permutation(a, a + n));
            int &max = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
            for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < vec.size(); ++j) {
                    int ni = vec[i], nj = vec[j];
                    if (ni + nj > max)
                        break;
                    if (std::binary_search(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ni + nj)) {
                        res.push_back(ni);
                        res.push_back(nj);
                        res.push_back(ni+nj);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    for (int i = start; i <= 9; i++) {
        a[level] = i;
        solve(a, level + 1, n, i, res);
    }
}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int func(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args,
     MArgument Res) {
    MTensor out;
    mint *out_data;
    int n = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
    std::vector<int> res;
    int *a = new int[n];
    solve(a, 0, n, 0, res);
    mint len = res.size();
    int err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 1, &len, &out);
    out_data = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(out);
    std::copy(res.begin(), res.end(), out_data);
    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, out);
    return 0;
}
";


Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
$CCompiler={"Compiler"->CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler,
"CompilerInstallation"->"C:/msys64/mingw64","CompilerName"->"g++.exe",
"CompileOptions"->"-O3"};

Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
LibraryUnload["func"];
lib=CreateLibrary[src,"func"];
func=LibraryFunctionLoad[lib,"func",{Integer},{Integer,1}];

Table[n -> AbsoluteTiming[Partition[func[n], 3] // Length], {n, 2, 8}] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I was wondering about (considering investigating) the use of `Compile` for this problem.

Comment: @AntonAntonov You are welcome.

Comment: If I'm correct, The numbers of 3-digit to 10-digit triples are: 1, 25, 648, 17338, 495014, 17565942, 717564880, 30694477548. How is the growth like?

Answer (score 2):

> But it took ages to give the output.

It took ~170 seconds on my computer; with [`ParallelTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html) it took ~97 seconds.

I assume two-times speed-up is not good enough, but it was very easy to get it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Divide the numbers from 1000 to 9999 into a few hundred sets of integers that have the same digits, for example [1234, 1243, 1324, 1342, 1423, 1432 ... ]. Then a and b must be in the same set, and a+b must be in that set as well. So you loop over the 400 or so sets S of integers, then iterate over all elements a < 5000 of the set S, iterate b over all elements of the set S with a ≤ b ≤ 9999-a, and then check if a+b is an element of S as well. Should take milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe out of slope...

Since this range is kind of huge. So use Python's Api maybe a better choice?

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "[(i, j, i+j)for i in range(1000, 9999) for j in range(i, 9999-i)
 if sorted(str(i)) == sorted(str(j)) == sorted(str(i+j))]"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

```
{27.2873, {{1089, 8019, 9108}, {1089, 8091, 9180}, {1269, 1692, 
            2961}, {1467, 6147, 7614}, {1467, 6174, 7641}, {1476, 4671, 
            6147}, {1503, 3510, 5013}, {1530, 3501, 5031}, {1746, 4671, 
            6417}, {2385, 2853, 5238}, {2439, 2493, 4932}, {2502, 2520, 
            5022}, {2538, 3285, 5823}, {2691, 6921, 9612}, {2853, 5382, 
            8235}, {3285, 5238, 8523}, {4095, 4950, 9045}, {4095, 5409, 
            9504}, {4392, 4932, 9324}, {4590, 4950, 9540}, {4599, 4995, 
            9594}, {4698, 4986, 9684}, {4797, 4977, 9774}, {4896, 4968, 
            9864}, {4959, 4995, 9954}}}
```

costs 27s

> Contrast to origin code which takes 233.128s on my PC.

Comment: (+1) but I was seriously contemplating to give this answer (-1). :)

Comment: This is Python, not Mathematica

Comment: @Raffaele "This is Python, not Mathematica" -- yes, but two things have to be said: **1.** This solution uses Python called within Mathematica with native (to Mathematica) input and output. **2.** Your (original) post finished with the question "Is there a way to speed up this procedure?" and this answer satisfies it.